# RowReduce doesn't work for this matrix?

Tags: functions

I have this matrix

```
A={{0,1,1,w},{1,0,1,x},{-1,0,1,y},{0,1,1,z}}
```

where w, x, y, z are arbitrary constants. This matrix should be row reduced to the form

```
{{1,0,0,1/2x-1/2y},{0,1,0, -1/2x-1/2y+w},{0,0,1,1/2x+1/2y},{0,0,0,w-z}}
```

However, applying the RowReduce[A] gives

```
{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}
```

I feel like I must have done something obviously wrong, but what is the problem?

Comment: Row Reduced /= Gaussian elimination. The result returned is correct. May be you meant `LUDecomposition[A]` which gives `{{1, 0, 1, x}, {0, 1, 1, w}, {-1, 0, 2, 1 + x}, {0, 1, 0, -w + z}}` ? I do not know how you obtained `{{1,0,0,1/2x-1/2y},{0,1,0, -1/2x-1/2y+w},{0,0,1,1/2x+1/2y},{0,0,0,w-z}}`

Comment: The result returned isn't correct, because the matrix is singular for $w=z$. I'm not sure why it isn't working, since the documentation provides examples where it works properly for symbolic matrices in 1 variable. Perhaps it's assuming all symbolic quantities are nonzero?

Comment: It's correct. `RowReduce` gives generic results, and in particular it does not separate into cases. If `PossibleZeroQ` gives `False` then a symbolic value is regarded as viable for use as a pivot.